# Reorder options of Datatables column visibility button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the Datatables plugin to display some data, with server-side processing. The sort order of the column visibility button's options matches the column order by default.
Is there any way to reorder the options of the Datatables column visibility button alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with an event handler

```
$(document).on("mouseup", ".buttons-colvis", function () {
  // I combined a mouseup event with a delay, because the elements appear to be selectable only after they have been displayed. There may be a better way to approach this
  setTimeout(function () {
    // Reorder elements alphabetically, based on text content
    $('.buttons-columnVisibility').sort(function (a, b) {
      if (a.textContent < b.textContent) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    }).appendTo('.dt-buttons .dropdown-menu'); //  re-attach to the dropdown menu
  }, 250);
});
```